# PHP sha1 file hashes - which method?

Tags: php, linux, sha1

What function to hash file should I use? I did some speed comparison and the second is about 1 second faster on bigger, 40 MB file, but PHP function is faster on small files. What is more correct to use?

```
$sha1 = sha1_file($path);

$sha1 = array_shift(explode(" ", `sha1sum $path`));
```